# I have downloaded ubuntu 12.10 but details tell I am using ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 12.10, 13.04

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 but details tell I am using Ubuntu 13.04. How is this possible?

Comment: We need a lot more details to answer your question.  What type of 12.10 did you download?  An ISO presumably?  Did you do anything with whatever you downloaded?  A download on its own doesn't do anything.

Comment: command "lsb_release -a" say 12.10 but the "Details" tab under "System Setting" displays 13.04.

I have downloaded 32 bit Ubuntu Desktop.

After installation I had changed the file manager to 1) nemo from Nautilus and 
2) added ppa - "ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3" and ran command "dist-upgrade"

Comment: Could you provide the output of the command `apt-cache policy`? Please **edit** your question to include new information - it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you see? :)

Comment: If the information [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254327/ubuntu-says-13-04-but-lsb-release-says-12-10) *doesn't* reveal the source of this problem, then it's a bug and should be [reported as such](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). See also [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) ([At least once before](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/690248), information from a newer release's help was wrongly synced into an older release's help. It affected many users. It was reported as a bug, then fixed.)